# Open access database (mdb) in sharing (among multiple users)

Tags: ms-access, macros

I have an access database (mdb) and I want to open create an "automatic system" that a third party user (I would say a stupid-user) could run a macro automatically. So I created a batch file and I run the command:

```
INOPENSPACE.mdb /nostartup /x MyMacro
```

The problem is that Access cannot open because it needs the exclusive rights. If I try to open it by myself I open without exclusive rights and run the same macro without problems. Is there any way to do this by a command line or same, or is there any way to open an access database without exclusive rights and run my macro?

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach this is to split the data into a separate database (data-db), and then create links to the tables in the database housing the macro (app-db).

The user would then have their own copy of the app-db, and not have to work if another user has opened it or not - they can always have exclusive access.